# Why does a target created from a custom xctemplate shows many build settings in the "User-Defined" section

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

I have created a custom XCode Project Template (.xctemplate), that can be used to build a fake iOS Framework. The Targets created by the template work fine, but there is one thing that bothers me: I can't get XCode to show Compiler-specific Build Settings in the Target's Build Settings Tab under the respective and well known sections (e.g.: "Apple LLVM Compiler 4.0 - Language", "Apple LLVM Compiler - Warnings - All Languages"). Instead, XCode puts all these settings in a section named "User-defined" and even renames some of the configured keys.

XCode version is 4.4.1 on a OSX 10.7.4 system.

The .xctemplate's TemplateInfo.plist starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Kind</key>
<string>Xcode.Xcode3.ProjectTemplateUnitKind</string>
<key>Identifier</key>
<string>com.blabla.iosFramework</string>
<key>Concrete</key>
<true/>
<key>Description</key>
<string>This is a template for fake iOS Frameworks</string>
<key>SortOrder</key>
<integer>3</integer>
<key>Ancestors</key>
<array>
    <string>com.apple.dt.unit.bundleBase</string>
    <string>com.apple.dt.unit.iPhoneBase</string>
</array>
<key>Targets</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>ProductType</key>
        <string>com.apple.product-type.bundle</string>
        <key>SharedSettings</key>
        <dict>
            <!-- Architectures -->
            <!-- unimportant -->

            <!-- Build Options -->
            <key>GCC_VERSION</key>
            <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string> 

            <!-- Apple LLVM Compiler - Language -->             
            <key>GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD</key>
            <string>gnu99</string>

            <!-- Apple LLVM Compiler - Warnings - All Languages -->
            <key>GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION</key>
            <string>YES</string>
            <key>GCC_WARN_SHADOW</key>
            <string>YES</string>
            <key>GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION</key>
            <string>YES</string>                
            <key>GCC_WARN_INITIALIZER_NOT_FULLY_BRACKETED</key>
            <string>YES</string>
            <key>GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE</key>
            <string>YES</string>
            <key>GCC_WARN_ABOUT_MISSING_PROTOTYPES</key>
            <string>YES</string>
            <key>GCC_WARN_UNINITIALIZED_AUTOS</key>
            <string>YES</string>
            <key>GCC_WARN_UNUSED_FUNCTION</key>
            <string>YES</string>
            <key>GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE</key>
            <string>YES</string>

            <!-- Apple LLVM Compiler - Warnings - Objective C -->
            <key>GCC_WARN_STRICT_SELECTOR_MATCH</key>
            <string>YES</string>
            <key>GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR</key>
            <string>YES</string>
        </dict>
        <key>BuildPhases</key>
```

Here's how the compiler-specific settings show up in XCode:

[image]

As I want to use this template to convert several static libraries into frameworks, it would be really helpful to have XCode show the Compiler-specific settings under the respective sections. What am I doing wrong?